# pb when opening file then re-saving

Tags: c#, serialization, save

I am creating a program that encrypts/hashs messages

I have a list that contains (date,user,encryption, message,encryptedmessage)
=> Variables.oHistorique.Liste_historique.

When I just encrypt messages then save it works fine, when I open that file the list contains all the information expected however if I open a file then re-save it (even under a new name) it's empty, the list is empty.
I appreciate all the help i can get
Thanks

P.S
I've checked and the list is populated when I save but not when i open the newly saved file

//when i click open

```
 private void ouvrirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileDialog location = new OpenFileDialog();
        location.Filter = "Data Files (*.dat)|*.dat";
        location.FilterIndex = 1;
        result = location.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
          Variables.oHistorique = (CHistorique)oSerialize.DeSerializeObject(location.FileName);
          for (int i = 0; i < Variables.oHistorique.Liste_historique.ToArray().Length; i++)
          {
              dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Variables.oHistorique.Liste_historique[i].Date, Variables.oHistorique.Liste_historique[i].User, Variables.oHistorique.Liste_historique[i].Type, Variables.oHistorique.Liste_historique[i].Chaine, Variables.oHistorique.Liste_historique[i].ChaineCrypt);
          }
          dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;  
        }
    }
```

//When I click on save :

```
private void sauvgarderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileDialog location = new SaveFileDialog();
        location.Filter = "Data Files (*.dat)|*.dat";
        location.FilterIndex = 1; 
        result = location.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {   
        oSerialize.SerializeObject(CHistorique.GetInstance(),location.FileName);
        }

    }
```

//Here's my class Serialize

```
 class CSerialize
{

    private static CSerialize Instance;

    private CSerialize()
    {

    }

    public void SerializeObject(object o, string file)
    {
        Stream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        b.Serialize(stream, o);
        stream.Close();
    }
    public object DeSerializeObject(string file)
    {
        Object o;
        Stream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        o = b.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return o;
    }
    public static CSerialize GetInstance()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = new CSerialize();
        }
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped your code in a debugger and watched the content of relevant objects in the save routine?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by relevant objects but in the debugger it enters the if statement properly and executes everything normally

Comment: Is CHistorique a singleton? If you're deserializing your data file into a second instance of it, then your "singleton" instance will not contain the deserialized data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
I replaced

```
oSerialize.SerializeObject(CHistorique.GetInstance(),location.FileName);
```

with

```
oSerialize.SerializeObject(Variables.oHistorique,location.FileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

From code you have provided I can see that when you deserialized an object you assigned it to static field of class Variables:

```
Variables.oHistorique = (CHistorique)oSerialize.DeSerializeObject(location.FileName);
```

but when you serializing object on save you try to access it through `CHistorique.GetInstance()` which as i can guess returns static field of class CHistorique (because it looks like singleton pattern). But from the code you have provided i don't see any connection between `Variables.oHistorique` and `CHistorique.GetInstance()` so may be problem lies here. You simply serializing empty variable, so file is empty.

Comment: I edited your post for others who have the same problem, 
I found the solution thanks to your post

Thanks alot I really appreciate it
Mike